# processing 2 - cannot find class or type named vector

Tags: vector, kinect, processing, openkinect

I'm trying to run an old processing sketch along with my kinect that saves kinect point cloud data as OBJ files, but I'm getting an error on this line:

Vector  recording = new Vector();

stating

cannot find a class or type named "Vector" - I am running processing 2. Did they get rid of this type? What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PVector](http://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) with Processing 2 instead of the old `Vector`.

```
PVector recording = new PVector(40, 20);
```

Answer (score 4):

import the `java.util.*;` library..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RomanC - I think it does provide an answer; I actually needed to use some old code that uses `.add()` method of `Vector` class - and seemingly `PVector` doesn't have that; but using `import java.util.*;` helped me run the patch again on Processing 2.

Comment: @sdaau I don't think so, it doesn't provide the answer or such answer should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @RomanC - so you're saying, if it did provide the answer, it should have been a comment - but it doesn't provide an answer, because it isn't a comment? Is it because it is not long enough? Second time I get stuck with this issue, and second time adding `import java.util.*;` at the top of my sketch made it run in Processing 2; ergo, I still see it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the code without changing anything, as `bluefeet` stated, putting `import java.util.*;` t the top of the sketch will compile the sketch.

I did the same thing for the PointCLoud sketch using Kinect, I'm going to take a guess and say it's the same sketch you're trying to run?

Once you've added `java.util.*;`, the sketch works without having to worry about converting it to `pvector` which causes more issues later in the sketch with the `[frame]` adding.